# A circular reference has been detected when serializing the object of class "App\Entity\Cronjobs"

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I'm getting  a circular reference error using ManyToOne on an entity object.
My entities look like:

```
class CronjobProperties
{

   /**
    * @ORM\Id()
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    */
   private $id;

   /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Cronjobs", inversedBy="cronjobProperties")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE", nullable=false)
    */
   private $cronjob;

   /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\CronjobProperties", inversedBy="children")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE")
    */
   private $parent;

   /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\CronjobProperties", mappedBy="parent", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"persist"})
    */
   private $children;

   /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
    */
   private $name;

   /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
    */
   private $value;

}
...



class CoreConfigData
{

    /**
    * @ORM\Id()
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    */
   private $id;

   /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Cronjobs")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE", nullable=false)
    */
   private $scope;

   /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
    */
   private $scopeName;

   /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
    */
   private $name;

   /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
    */
   private $value;

   /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
    */
   private $path;

   /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
    */
   private $environment;

   ...



class Cronjobs
{
   /**
    * @ORM\Id()
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    */
   private $id;

   /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
    */
   private $name;

   /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
    */
   private $command;

   /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\CronjobProperties", mappedBy="cronjob",  orphanRemoval=true)
    */
   private $cronjobProperties;

   /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\CoreConfigData", mappedBy="scope", orphanRemoval=true)
    */
   private $coreSettings;

    /**
     * @return Collection|CronjobProperties[]
     *
     */
     public function getCronjobProperties(): Collection
     {
        return $this->cronjobProperties;
     }
```

Basically the 'Cronjobs' table is related with OneToMany to the 'CronjobProperties' table using the 'cronjob' field on the 'CronjobProperties' table and with OneToMany to the 'CoreConfigData' table using the 'scope' field.
So both CronjobProperties and CoreConfigData are connected to Cronjobs table.

I'm getting the issue when I introduced the third entity and added another OneToMany to the Cronjobs table

I also tried with Groups and MaxDepth changing the Cronjobs entity like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\CronjobsRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="w_cronjobs", uniqueConstraint={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="unique_name_command", columns={"name", "command"})})
 */
class Cronjobs
{

   /**
    * @Groups("cronjob")
    * @ORM\Id()
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    */
   private $id;

   /**
    * @Groups("cronjob")
    * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
    */
   private $name;

   /**
    * @Groups("cronjob")
    * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
    */
   private $command;

   /**
    * @MaxDepth(2)
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\CronjobProperties", mappedBy="cronjob", orphanRemoval=true)
    */
   private $cronjobProperties;

   /**
    * @MaxDepth(2)
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\CoreConfigData", mappedBy="scope", orphanRemoval=true)
    */
   private $coreSettings;

   /**
    * @return Collection|CronjobProperties[]
    *
    */
    public function getCronjobProperties(): Collection
    {
       return $this->cronjobProperties;
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand how serialization groups can help on that answer. I'm getting the issue when I introduced the third entity and added another OneToMany to the Cronjobs table. In that question the person is getting the issue when creating a new entity. I'm getting the issue while fetching data.

Comment: This one as well  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59268438/symfony-4-a-circular-reference-has-been-detected-when-serializing-the-object-o

Comment: Serialization groups are used when fetching data, exactly.

Comment: I tried both options proposed there but they don't work. I will update in a moment the question

Comment: I now discovered and that's odd, that if I remove the getCrojobProperties GETTER , it works. If I Ignore it to the serializer it doesn't work. ??

Comment: I guess it’s something with the lazy loading. Try to avoid the lazy loading and fetch the entire data before serializing.